# Error while fetching tweets using TweetSharp API

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to fetch all tweets from a particular Hashtag using `TweetSharp API`. I am using these following codes for this

```
public ActionResult AddTwitterDataTop(TwitterData objTwitterData)
{
    try
    {
        var service = new TwitterService(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
        service.AuthenticateWith(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
        var tweets = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "#MisuseOfRapeLaw", Count = 100, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Recent });
        IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status = tweets.Statuses;
        foreach (var item in status)
        {
            var qry = (from s in ObjEdbContext.ObjTwitterDatas where s.Text == item.Text && s.ScreenName == item.User.ScreenName select s).FirstOrDefault();
            if (qry != null) continue;
            objTwitterData.ScreenName = item.User.ScreenName;
            objTwitterData.UserName = item.User.Name;
            objTwitterData.Text = item.Text;
            objTwitterData.RetweetCount = item.RetweetCount;
            objTwitterData.FavouritesCount = item.User.FavouritesCount;
            objTwitterData.ProfileImageUrl = item.User.ProfileImageUrl;
            objTwitterData.TimeStam = item.CreatedDate;
            objTwitterData.RetweetUrlId = "https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=" + item.Id;
            objTwitterData.ReplyaUrlId = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=" + item.Id;
            objTwitterData.FavoriteUrlId = "https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=" + item.Id;
            objTwitterData.IsValid = "Pending";
            ObjEdbContext.ObjTwitterDatas.Add(objTwitterData);
            ObjEdbContext.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Some exception occured" + e;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Some times it works fine and some times gives the following exception after this line

`var tweets = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "#MisuseOfRapeLaw", Count = 100, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Recent });`

> JSON integer 2265545852 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'statuses[19].in_reply_to_user_id', line 1, position 60279.

If I change my count to 18 instead of 100 it works fine.

The above code returns only 100 data which is mixed of Tweets and Re-tweets.
Is there any way to achieve these

1. Fetch all the tweets(Mixed of Tweets and Re-tweets) not 100.
2. Fetch only Tweets using Filter(No Re-tweets).

There are many Q&A in SO similar to this question but none of them actually helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of TweetSharp currently published to Nuget doesn't support long integer id's for many things (users etc). If your search results return a tweet from a user who has a large id, it will fail with this error.

The source code in the nuget repository for TweetSharp does include a fix for this, so if you are able to get and build the code yourself and reference the binaries you built the problem should go away.

If you don't want to go to that effort, you need to use one of the forks of TweetSharp (the original TweetSharp is no longer being maintained). There are a few alternate packages on Nuget TweetMoaSharp (which I primarily maintain at this time) or TweetSharp-Alternate. Alternatively, you could change to an entirely different library such as LinqToTwitter.